# Javascript: Get the value with the html tags from the textarea as with tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, htmltext

When I am using TinyMCE, the value I am geting from is in HTML, also with HTML tags.
Is there a possibility to get the same from a textarea?

When I am trying

```
var text= $('#myTextarea').val();
```

I am geting only the simple text, without html tags.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using .html() rather than .val()?

Comment: Thank you @DanPrince, I try this righnow but Iam geting an empty string in this case.

Comment: Thank you @am not i am, but that's not my goal. May be I shuld add some more precision to my question. What I need is: for example in tinyMCE, when i will write "aaaaa" then go to a new line and then write "bbb", i wil get this value: "aaa<br />bbb" and with the textarea, I am geting "aaa" then in the second line "bbb" and I would like to get  "aaa<br />bbb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems than the text and textarea are returning only plain text, and no html. We need to use tinyMCE in this case.

Comment: Yes, I think you're asking a little too much of a simple textarea component. If it's only new lines you care about then you could convert them yourself, but then there's entity escaping and other things to be considered. You're probably best off using something like TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use outerHTML property to get "tag source"

for simple input with id="inputId" you will get "`<input type="text" id="inputId">`"

in your case try

```
var text = $('#myTextarea')[0].outerHTML
```